# Resolve specific domain to localhost on Ubuntu and OpenVPN

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, openvpn

I have a PC connected to my ubuntu OpenVPN server.

what I'm trying to do is making google.com resolve to my IP address instead of Google IP address when I browser google.com on my client pc.

#### Attempts

I have tried editing the **hosts file** on my openVPN server and I was pretty sure it will not work.

Also I tried to get domain IP address and redirect it using **iptables** but it didn't work as well.

I think that I need to have a dns server or something easier, any suggests?

Note: I don't want to edit my hosts file on client pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup [DNSMasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) on the VPN server and have it override google.com using an address directive

```
address=/google.com/192.0.2.2/
```

Substitute your IP address as appropriate.

Push DNS server information to the client such that it will use the VPN server as it's DNS server.

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.0.10.1"
```

Where 10.0.10.1 is the address of your OpenVPN interface.

Comment: should I add `address=/google.com/192.0.2.2/` to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` right? how do I get my openVPN interface?

Comment: Yes and erm it's whatever you set it up to be tun0 ??? On Linux `ip address show` would list it while  OpenVPN is running

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have installed DNSMasq from this [tutorial](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-configure-dnsmasq-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/) and added  `address=/google.com/192.0.2.2/` to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf ` then on my client openVPN config file added `push "dhcp-option DNS 10.0.8.1"` but it didn't work :(

Comment: `...It didn't work :(` is a useless statement. You'll just have to roll up your sleeves,  dust off you scientific method and apply your sysadmin skills to solving the problem yourself.

Comment: @lain you are right, I'm sorry, I thought we've just missed something or I did something wrong so added work summary in my comment. I'm already rolled up my sleeves and trying hard to solve the problem and asking you for your help.

Comment: My client PC connected to the openVPN server and I'm using system dns resolvers on my openVPN server. but nothing really changed on my PC whatever domain I add to `dnsmasq` even though dnsmasq resolve them on my openVPN server, can you help me track down where the problem is?

Comment: /etc/resolv.conf